# state undefined in location react router dom link

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-props

component 1 passing the state through link's to

```
<Link to={{
        pathname: "/Dashboard",
        state: { color: "red" }
    }}>
```

component 2 receiving the state

```
import React from 'react';

export interface DashboardProps {
  location: any;
}

export interface DashboardState {

}

class Dashboard extends React.Component<DashboardProps, DashboardState> {

  render() {
    console.log("props", this.props.location);

    return (
      <h1>dashboard</h1>
    );
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

result

[image]

main component render

```
   public render() {
    return (
      <HashRouter>
        <div>
          <Route path="/Dashboard" render={(props: any) => (<Dashboard {...props} />)} />
        </div>
      </HashRouter >
    )
  }
```

I believe I don't need to wrap my dashboard(component to receive state through link react router dom)
with "withRouter"

Answer (score 4):

what a pity ! HashRouter doesn't support location.state:
You can see here https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/7628 or https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/HashRouter.md

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include the most important and relevant information from the links provided in the answer itself. This helps to ensure your answer doesn't become invalid if the links stop working or the content significantly changes.

Answer (score 1):

Hashrouter doesn't support location.key and location.state. Go through the documentation here https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).